# Objective C Syntax Error? CS193 CalculatorViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios5, cs193p

I've come across a fair number questions with the same file and after cleaning out my other errors there's still one i can't seem to figure out. I think the error is that I have one too many/few { or } but after trying a number of variation, I'm stuck.

I would really appreciate a second set of eyes on this... thanks!

Immediately below shows section in question, the error is being shown at { else }

```
- (IBAction)digitPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSString *digit = sender.currentTitle;
    if (self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber); {
      self.display.text = [self.display.text stringByAppendingString:digit];
    } else {
        self.display.text = digit;
        self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber = YES;
    }
}
```

The complete file is inserted blow

```
#import "CalculatorViewController.h"
#import "CalculatorBrain.h"

@interface CalculatorViewController ()
@property (nonatomic) BOOL userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CalculatorBrain *brain;
@end

@implementation CalculatorViewController

@synthesize display = _display;
@synthesize userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber = _userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber;
@synthesize brain = _brain;

- (CalculatorBrain *)brain
{
    if (!_brain) _brain = [[CalculatorBrain alloc] init];
    return _brain;
}
- (IBAction)digitPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSString *digit = sender.currentTitle;
    if (self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber); {
      self.display.text = [self.display.text stringByAppendingString:digit];
    } else {
        self.display.text = digit;
        self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber = YES;
    }
}

- (IBAction)enterPressed
{
    [self.brain pushOperand:[self.display.text doubleValue]];
        self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber = NO;
}

- (IBAction)operationPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if (self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber) [self enterPressed];
    double result = [self.brain performOperation:sender.currentTitle];

    NSString *resultString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", result];
    self.display.text = resultString;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have ";" after your if statement

```
if (self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra semicolon on this line:

```
if (self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber); {
```